# How can i use automaticly variable while i using api in flutter?

Tags: flutter

```
Future userProfile() async {
    var headers = {
      'Max-Forwards': '',
      'X-Culture': 'tr_TR',
      'Authorization':  globals.token
    };
    var response = await http.get(
        Uri.parse('link'),
        headers: headers);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      String data = response.body;

      userName = jsonDecode(data)[0]['name'];
    } else {
      print(response.reasonPhrase);
    }
  }
```

when i debug code Text widget is coming null. But if i use ctrl+s my data is using in Text widget. How can i do it directliy ?

Comment: you call your text widget over the future, and you can share your text widget code

Comment: so how can i do it ? could you give me source or tips ?

Comment: you can share your source code of text code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add setState

```
 setState(() {
     userName = jsonDecode(data)[0]['name'];
}) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Stack(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        width: double.infinity,
                        height: 50,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 20, 20, 10),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey, width: 1),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                          shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                        ),
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                          child: TextWidget(
                            text: "$userName",
                            size: 20,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Positioned(
                          left: 50,
                          top: 12,
                          child: Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                bottom: 10, left: 10, right: 10),
                            color: Colors.white,
                            child: Text(
                              'Name',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 12),
                            ),
                          )),
                    ],
                  ),
```

here

Comment: Please explain your solution. Answers which do not have an explanation and are only code get flagged as low effort.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.